# Smarty assign id to {assign} variable

Tags: javascript, foreach, smarty, smarty3

How can assign an ID to an {assign}'s variable and increment it?

```
{assign var="end" value=$Product->Price}
```

I need to increment inside a {foreach} the variable "end" to "end1", "end2", n...

```
{assign var="end" value=$Product->Price}
{assign var="end1" value=$Product->Price}
{assign var="end2" value=$Product->Price}
```

At least I will call in javascript this variables as a class to run it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should help:

```
{assign var="end" value=$Product->Price}

{for $i=1 to 3}
    {assign var="end{$i}" value=$Product->Price}
{/for}
```

Debug:

```
{$end|var_dump}
{$end1|var_dump}
{$end2|var_dump}
{$end3|var_dump}
```